# NumberFormatException when parsing Hindi numbers

Tags: java, android

I have an android application and today I have got a crash report which contains this:
[image: NumberFormatException]

This exception trigger when the application tries to parse string number which is provided by the user.

It is obvious that problem is the application cannot parse Hindi numbers! So, how can I solve this?

Comment: Please **don't** post images of the errors, copy and paste it in plain text.

Comment: Is this an application you're writing? I can't be sure at the moment,

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza The font and SO localization may not support pasting the characters in question.

Comment: If you could show us your code, we might be more able to help you.

Comment: I think only way is, create a map of Hindi number equivalent to regular Number and do map lookup.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Sorry I had to do that. Because, the number was not displayed as it should be.

Comment: @Nambari I would try your solution, but do you think that this way is efficient to deal with the problem.

Comment: I don't think that is efficient, but work around. See if Anirudh solutions works? If not, I think no other way.

Answer (score 4):

## Regex

Using regex would be better if you want to match any unicode digits.The regex would be `\\p{N}+` and here's how to use it:

```
Matcher m=Pattern.compile("\\p{N}+").matcher(input);
if(m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

## Locale

To answer your question you should use [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) as mentioned in [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29). Specify a [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) for [`NumberFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html).

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("hi", "IN"));
nf.parse(input);
```

Comment: What did you mean about regex? Seems like the NumberFormat with Locale is a complete solution.

Comment: @BasilBourque you can match any unicode digits via regex `\\p{N}+`..I will edit the ans

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Character.getNumericValue(char)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue%28char%29).

The good thing about this method is that it can do what you need.

But to work in valid you should implement in your application support for local.

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("hin","IND"));

Number parse = format.parse("१");

System.out.println(parse);
```

Prints `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This will remove non numeric characters.

```
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)"); 
  Matcher m = p.matcher(str); // str is input String
  while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
  }
```

If you are dealing with `double`(with decimal places). you can try this

```
    String text = "123.0114cc";
    String numOnly = text.replaceAll("\\p{Alpha}","");
    double numVal = Double.valueOf(numOnly);
    System.out.println(numVal);
```

Comment: Thank you but this won't solve the problem (I guess). Because the characters above are numbers but in Hindi format. Therefore, if I tried your solution the result will be zero all the time whenever the user tries to enter a number.

Comment: ohh then you have to know witch number assign to witch Hindi character and make a Map<String,Integer>

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(YOUR_VALUE);
```

before applying the regex, as the BigDecimal supports 12 integers, 12.35 decimal, and  12 $ currency, 12% percentage and its localized value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method which receives a string and converts every Indian digit inside it to Arabic.

```
public static String convertAllIndianToArabic(String str)
{
    for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
    {
        if(str.charAt(i)=='٠')
            str = str.substring(0, i)+"0"+str.substring(i+1);
        else if(str.charAt(i)=='١')
            str = str.substring(0, i)+"1"+str.substring(i+1);
        else if(str.charAt(i)=='٢')
            str = str.substring(0, i)+"2"+str.substring(i+1);
        else if(str.charAt(i)=='٣')
            str = str.substring(0, i)+"3"+str.substring(i+1);
        else if(str.charAt(i)=='٤')
            str = str.substring(0, i)+"4"+str.substring(i+1);
        else if(str.charAt(i)=='٥')
            str = str.substring(0, i)+"5"+str.substring(i+1);
        else if(str.charAt(i)=='٦')
            str = str.substring(0, i)+"6"+str.substring(i+1);
        else if(str.charAt(i)=='٧')
            str = str.substring(0, i)+"7"+str.substring(i+1);
        else if(str.charAt(i)=='٨')
            str = str.substring(0, i)+"8"+str.substring(i+1);
        else if(str.charAt(i)=='٩')
            str = str.substring(0, i)+"9"+str.substring(i+1);

    }

    return str;
}
```